# Picard Approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

Consider the initial value problem 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 + 3x^2 - 1, \\
y(1) = 1$$

on D = {|x-1| <= 1, |y-1| <= 1}

Find the second approximation to the solution and estimate the error term

If someone could maybe walk me through the steps that would be most appreciated =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given:

$$\tag 1 \frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 + 3x^2 - 1, y(1) = 1, ~\mbox{on}~~ D = {|x-1| \le 1, |y-1| \le 1}$$

The Picard-Lindelöf iteration is given by:

$$\tag 2 \displaystyle y_0(x) = y_0, ~~y_{n+1}(x) = y_0 + \int^x_{x_0} f(s, y_n(s))ds$$

For $(1)$, we have: $f(s, y_n(s)) = y_n^2+3s^2-1$ and using $(2)$, yields:

- $\displaystyle y_0(1) = y_0 = 1$
- $\displaystyle y_1(x) = y_0 + \int^x_{x_0} f(s, y_0(s))ds = 1 + \int^x_{1} ((1)^2+3s^2-1) ds = x^3$
- $\displaystyle y_2(x) = y_0 + \int^x_{x_0} f(s, y_1(s))ds = 1 + \int^x_{1} ((s^3)^2+3s^2-1) ds = \dfrac{x^7}{7}+x^3-x +\dfrac{6}{7}$

If you need one more iteration, you would get:

$$y_3(x) = \frac{x^{15}}{735}+\frac{2 x^{11}}{77}-\frac{2 x^9}{63}+\frac{3 x^8}{98}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{2 x^5}{5}+\frac{3 x^4}{7}+\frac{4 x^3}{3}-\frac{6 x^2}{7}-\frac{13 x}{49}+\frac{4099}{6930}$$

Comment: thanks but for $y_1(x)$ shouldn't it be $2 + x^3$? due to the 1 + at the front of the integral?

Comment: ahhh wait never mind! the integral is $x^3 - 1$ so the ones cancel :) thanks!

Comment: Amzoti: Getting *very* close to $40$K! ;-)

Comment: @Kennan So you found an estimate for the error term in this answer?